# Why is Xamarin Page Template absent after updating Xamarin Forms?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

After updating Xamarin Forms `v2.0.0.6482` to `v2.3.1.114`, I noticed that when creating a new page, the `Cross-Platform` tab, normally containing `Forms ContentPage`, `Forms ContentView` and `Forms Xaml Page` templates disappeared. What could be the problem? I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Comment: You try to reinstall the xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing .suo file file from the project solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing and reinstalling the Xamarin.Forms package from your solution. This can be done via Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet packages for Solution.

“Walkthrough: Including a NuGet in your project”  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/nuget_walkthrough/ (you can select Visual Studio at top right of page)